# Having trouble with quotes in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have `$("input[name='bibble'").val(0);`

I want to put it into the onclick method of an input. However it clashes with the quotes:

```
<span onclick="$("input[name='bibble'").val(0);">...</span>
```

I have tried escaping the double quotes inside the onclick method with backslash and `""` but razor complains about both. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: Perhaps `<span onclick="$('input[name='bibble']').val(0);">...</span>`?

Comment: Also you have mismatched brackets, change `)` to `]`.

Comment: FWIW, this really has nothing to do with Razor or even ASP.NET MVC. This is just straight HTML/JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span onclick="$('input[name=bibble]').val(0);">...</span>`

the attribute name in the selector does not have to be quoted

Comment: Definitely the easiest way to solve the issue. Also, it's pretty typical to use single-quote strings when dealing with JavaScript, anyways, mostly because it's so prevalent to also be dealing with HTML in your JavaScript, and HTML uses double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can do this as you want, it looks a little unreadable. I'd probably do something slightly different:

```
<span onclick="setVal("bibble", 0);">...</span>
```

And the js function:

```
function setVal(inputName, val) {
    $("input[name="+inputName+"]).val(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your markup.

1. Mismatched `]` at the end of your `input[name=]`
2. The input name does not [need quotes](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-form-elements-by-name/).
3. You need to switch to single quotes inside of the double quotes for the `onclick=""` so that you do not have mismatched quotes in your onclick property.

Press the Run Code Snippet below to see it in action (click on the 'Click Me' span)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" name="bibble" id="test"/><br/>
<span onclick="$('input[name=bibble]').val(0)">Click me</span>
```